# Filtrar registros en Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

Tengo esta estructura de Fire Database

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesito encontrar un "cuadro" específico, lo hago en Angular

```
url = 'https://box-xxxyyy.firebaseio.com';

  getBox( box: string) {

    return this.http.get<any>(`${ this.url }/box/${ box }.json`)
      .pipe(
        map( res => {
          return res;
         } )
      );

  }
```

Pero si necesito encontrar todos los registros que tienen "rojo" en el campo "color", ¿cómo lo hago?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si miras la documentación sobre el filtrado de datos, obtenemos una consulta como esta, utilizando los parámetros de cadena de consulta orderBy e equalTo:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${ this.url }/box/${ box }.json?orderBy="color"&equalTo="red"`)
```